# Else condition always happening

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code the else condition always happens, even if the two variables are different. If I remove it it works just as it should, but has empty spots where "No" should be written.

```
For i = 2 To lRowMas    'Loop through all rows in Master Sheet
    For j = 2 To lRowCurrentSheet    'Loop through all rows in sheet to compare
        If Sheets(masterSheet).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(sheetNamesAsArray(x)).Cells(j, 1) Then
            Sheets(masterSheet).Cells(i, x + 2).Value = "Yes" 'set value to Yes
        Else
            Sheets(masterSheet).Cells(i, x + 2).Value = "No" 'set value to Yes
        End If
    Next j  'End inner loop, on sheet to compare
Next i  'End outer loop, on MasterSheet
```

Comment: Other than making sure that you compare cell values rather than cells, as pointed out in @AlwaysData 's answer below, another common source of this kind of consternation is the use of variables of Double type. Excel will use this type by default to express precise calculations. Doubles of similar value may differ by a tiny fraction (like 0.0000001) which makes no difference to the displayed value but shows up in a numeric comparison. If you have such values in the cells you compare they should be rounded before comparison.

Comment: What those two cells being compared actually contain? i.e. what datatype, text, numbers or what?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning. They are integers.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. I forgot to add a End For, so once it found a match and wrote yes, it would overwrite it with no in the next iteration. Thank you all for your advice.